# Current limit to 500mA (maximum) at 12V

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, dc, current-limiting, circuit-protection

I have a 12V DC output which can output 1A (maximum.)

I want a circuit that limits the current to maximum 500mA, so I don't accidentally draw more than 500mA as that would probably mean I have shorted something out.

If someone can help with a circuit that can limit the current to 500mA (max), so it doesn't output more than 500mA or opens the circuit if more than 500mA is drawn, please suggest which parts to use and the circuit.

Comment: I usually use a "***poly fuse***"

Comment: Please tell more what would be the exact use case, what power supply and what load? I would think that if you have a device which can't handle 12V 1A being miswired, it sure won't handle 12V 500mA either without damage.

Comment: @tlfong01 I cant find it in the online electronic store (electronicscomp), and it is somewhere showing 250V, but I only have 12V

Comment: @Manav Sengupta, the polyfuse actually doesn't care about voltage.  In other words, 500mA polyfuse, or ordinary  fuse, works in 12VDC or 250VAC.  
(1) Resettable fuse - Wikipedia, 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse
(2) PolyFuse - AliExpress.
https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-resettable-polyfuse.html

Comment: @Justme My use case is just project use and tinkering, I want to make a home-made 12V power supply with 12V adapter which gives 5V , 9V, 12V and has all sort of protection so I can safely play with it without doing any permanent damage to the circuit, so I want to have a max 500mA limit circuit for protection.

Comment: @ManavSengupta Also look up current foldback circuits. These can work quite well. I've used them and written about designing one here.

Comment: @tlfong01 So can these work ? : 100mA 250V Fast Acting Glass Fuse  
  
(https://www.electronicscomp.com/electronic-components/small-electronic-components/fuse/100-ma-250v-glass-fuse-20mm)

Comment: @Manav Sengupta, Ha, yes, "glass fuse" is what I referred earlier to as "ordinary" fuse. Actually I often use two fuses (fast poly, slow glass) in series, for "double" protection. One more thing, when I said (loosely) that voltage does not matter, actually some are of 30V, 60V, or 250V. They also have fast, slow  blow etc.   Ref: Example LittleFuse datasheet: https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=838e11ee-f2e4-4ce3-807b-8c47af72432c&filename=littelfuse-ptc-radial-leaded-ahrf-datasheet

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a current limiting diode in series with the supply?

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg Would you explain what is a current limiting diode and how it would work in series with a supply?

Comment: PhilFreedenberg I am not aware of commercial current limiting diodes that can handle 500 mA. You might be able to roll your own. @JustMe A current limiting diode is essentially a depletion mode JFET with a resistor between the gate and drain, packaged as a two terminal device. It does what it's name says, limits current. However, they are typically in the mA range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a circuit like this one:
[image]

Choose the transistors in such way that Q1 VCE will drop 0.7V when collector current is 500mA. This will trigger Q2 to shutoff Q1.To reset the circuit just remove the source and connect it again.

[image]

For a more precise current limit, independent of transistor gain, you can use the circuit below. Rsense is calculated as 0.4V / current. In your case 0.4V / 0.5A = 0.8ohm. However, you will need RB to be such that it draws 50mA, or more, as the circuit will be triggered when VCE is 0.3V and not 0.7V.
[image]

I have done some spice tests and here are the results when I vary the resistance of the load to show how the current varies and when Q1 shuts off.

Here is the chart of Q1 current:
[image]

You have to read the x-axis from 100ohm to 10ohm. And here is the spice code:
[image]

The way the circuit works is the following:

1. It uses the pass transistor (Q1) Collector to Emitter voltage (VCE) drop to trigger Q2.
2. When Q1 VCE is high enough (around 0.7 volts) it will make Q2 conduct.
3. When Q2 conducts because its base is 0.7V or higher, its VCE will lower Q1 Base to Emitter voltage below 0.7V, so Q1 base will not conduct anymore and it will shut off.
4. The trick here is that both transistors need to be driven in a such way that their collector to emitter voltage (VCE) is below the threshold of conduction of the base to emitter of the other transistor.
5. When Q1 is conducting, its collector to emitter (VCE) is below 0.7V so Q2 is off.
6. When Q1 VCE reaches 0.7V or higher, it triggers Q2 to conduct.
7. When Q2 conducts, it shuts off Q1. Detail, when Q2 is conducting, its VCE needs to be below 0.7V to keep Q1 off.

I have only done this circuit with BC557 which only draws a maximum of 100mA. So, I decided to do it with the BC327 and here are the results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have used an LED and 1K resistor to indicate when the circuit was ON.
The 0.4A current was when ON, and the 0.05A when it was OFF. The 0.05A is the current on Q2 when the circuit if OFF.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132833/discussion-on-answer-by-victortito-current-limit-to-500ma-max-at-12v).

Answer (score 3):

The circuit by Victor is not stable, and will not provide the protection you want. It is based on a technique called "dangle-biasing". It relies on the gain of the transistor being absolutely constant as the transistor heats up, and this is not true.

Here is a much better 2-transistor current limit circuit.  As with all simple limiter circuits, the output voltage will decrease slightly until the current limit is reached.  In this case, the output voltage will decrease from 12 V at 0 mA to approximately 11.4 V  when the the output current is at the limit defined by Rsense.

[Help dimensioning resistors in a two NPN transistor current limiter circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/288388/help-dimensioning-resistors-in-a-two-npn-transistor-current-limiter-circuit)

Comment: Tested. Confirmed for "dangle-biaising".

Answer (score 3):

If one can tolerate a little voltage drop ...

Here is a "circuit" that can do it ... In fact, it is a "classic" power supply. R1&R11 limit the current as usual. **Internal impedance** = ~ **0.6 Ohm**. Can be used also to other "fix" voltages.

Some components may be "omitted". R10 & X2 ( 10V zener).

[image]

And if someone is interested in a **"foldback" protection**, one can use this schematic.

The **internal impedance** (because of the op-amp) is here **0.013 Ohm** from 0mA to the "foldback point", here 300mA.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This circuit gives you an adjustable current limit.  The current is sensed by R_POT.  When the voltage across R_POT becomes high enough to turn on Q2, then Q2 will begin turning off Q1, which will restrict current flow.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOB13o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**COMPONENT SELECTION:**

- Q2 may be just about any PNP transistor that has a VCE_sat < 0.5V.
- Q1 must be a PNP transistor that is rated to handle several watts of power.  Something like a TO-220 screwed to the appropriate heat sink (which could just be some sheet metal if you had no other option).
- R2 biases Q1 base.  Something around 500 ohms to 1K is a good choice depending on the gain of Q1.  Due to the limited current gain of Q1, R2 imposes an additional limit on the output current regardless of R_POT.  It's a good idea to select R2 as high a value as will work reliably.
- R_POT selects the output current limit.  The current limit is roughly 0.7V / R_POT.  R_POT should be rated to handle around 1W to be safe.

Comment: Will Q1 always be dissipating near 6W of power ?

Comment: Yes Manav, this is a constant current circuit that will be drawing current and heat (that is why it needs the heat sink) while the output is shorted.

Comment: You can use a PMOS for Q1..They are more ubiquitous at higher powers, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @ManavSengupta If the current limit is set to 500mA and the output of the limiter is shorted to ground then there would be roughly 11.3V across Q1.  In that case Q1 would dissipate 5.65W.  Under normal circumstances there should be less than 0.5V across Q1, so it would probably dissipate under 1/4W for any current lower than the limit setting.

Answer (score 1):

Using a fuse is the cheapest & easiest way, you can find resettable & non-resettable fuses on local stores. I was able to find the in Hyderabad. You can also get them delivered to India via RS components.

Comment: Agreed, I have ordered many glass fuses too for backup (I will buy those ressetable ones later when I order next time from RS components), but I have seen and used a Relay based short-circuit protection many times, so I was wondering if something like that could be made for over-current too, using relay or transistors, so I want to try that, and maybe learn something in the process.

Comment: On the other hand you could use OPAMPs & current sense resistors to limit the current. This is relatively complex & requires knowledge of differential amplifiers & current sense resistors. Single comment is not enough to cover all of this.

Comment: No that is too complex for me now, I wont be able to use them, Coming up with an auto shut off circuit for overcurrent was too complicated for me thats why I asked, and I want to try out Victors answer when the components arrive, and I will have fuses too, if I fail to make that , then I will simply use the fuse, but still thanks for the suggestion, In distant future I might be able to use those opamps etc. when I learn more about Electronics.