# Rewinding a 6 V DC motor and decreasing inrush current

Tags: inrush-current, winding, calculation

I have a small simple 6 V DC motor and I would like to rewind its rotor. The motor has 2 magnets. The rotor has 3 poles to wind. Normally each part has 169 turns of winding with 0.15 mm<sup>2</sup> copper wire.

My intention is re-winding those coils, but I would like to know before winding how many turns and what thickness of wire I need. I want to make calculations, however, I don't know anything more than the information above.

Comment: why are you rewinding the motor?

Comment: Are you rewinding the rotor to try to decrease inrush current?  There are easier ways to go about that.

Comment: Rewinding a motor and decreasing inrush current are usually two different things.  When you explain why you're rewinding the motor, please don't stop at "to reduce inrush current".  Please explain _what you're trying to achieve with the assembly_.

Comment: You can decrease stall current by increasing the number of turns, but it will also reduce speed and power output. Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rewinding the motor, consider using a current limiter. This can be constructed from two transistors and two resistors.

More here: [Help dimensioning resistors in a two NPN transistor current limiter circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/288388/help-dimensioning-resistors-in-a-two-npn-transistor-current-limiter-circuit)